# Steady rankings but impressions dropped off a cliff

Tags: google-search-console, search-engine-indexing

[image: search console]I run a website in the 'Christmas song lyrics' niche and have been slowly but building traffic. However, after updating content and urls to better Target the niche Google has been go a bit wild on the site with rankings doing the google dance.

However, for certain keywords impressions have dropped off a cliff but the position has been steady. I cannot figure this out for the life of me.

Please help.

Comment: When did you update your content? Was it immediately before the drop?

Comment: Nope the url had been changed about 1 month prior. Added breadcrumbs around this time. FYI the site is on shopify

Comment: Years ago we saw something similar with a couple of our keywords, and as I remember, our PM did some investigation and concluded the most probable cause was that Google tweaked its algorithm that trigger keywords for queries. I wonder if Google has a support channel/contact that can help you pin this down.

Answer (score 1):

Impressions depends on the number of people searching for those terms.   It is not surprising that there are very few impressions for many terms around "Christmas song lyrics" in July.

I would expect impressions to pick up in October when radio stations start playing Christmas music, peak in December, and fall off again in January.   This type of seasonality is common in many niches.

Comment: Even though it is only happening on some keywords?

Comment: Seasonality is different for every keyword.   In general I'd expect most Christmas keywords to not have much traffic in July.

Comment: I just find it strange that all of a sudden impressions drop within one day to almost zero. I have added a screenshot of search console.